# Heat transfer of a water body like fish pond and lake

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, measurements

As an introduction, I am a computer engineering student that want to create an arduino project in which it use water temperature as its parameter. The temperature will help the microcontroller choose whether it should turn on the heater or not. But in planning this project, I cannot decide how many heater and how many temperature sensor I should put. Do I need to measure the temperature in different spots of water because temperature difference in each spot? How the heat will propagate from one spot to another? Will there be an area in which the heat isn't spread enough from the heater so I need an extra heater in that spot? The body of water that I'm using is relatively calm like a pond and lake.

Comment: What's your objective? To keep all of the water at the desired temperature? And what are you using as a heater? As a starting point, heat flow can be modeled as a diffusion equation. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation]

Comment: @netflix_and_physics yes my objective is to keep the water in desired temperature. As I will use fish pond in my project, I will try to use 300W aquarium heater. Can I somehow get how far the heat be propagated through the water with that? So maybe I can divide the fish pond to several part that fit the maximum heat propagation distance from the heater